# How to exit after certain days from `strategy.entry`

Tags: stock, pine-script, trading

I can't seem to figure out the syntax for exit a trade from a certain time interval from the trade entry. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
    strategy.exit("Exit", "Long", when = 15)
```

The code above I want to `exit` the long position after 15 days. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out one solution. I created another `if` statement but offset by 15 days to trigger. I also set the crossover to a variable. See code:

```
buy = (crossover(delta, 0))

if (buy)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment="Long")
if (buy[15])
    strategy.close("Long")
```

Answer (score 5):

Try **barssince**

```
// Example - Buy when the price closes below 22

myEntry = close  < 22

strategy.entry(id= "sample", long = strategy.long, when= myEntry)

// Close 10 bar periods after the condition that triggered the entry

strategy.close(id = "sample", when = barssince(myEntry) >= 10)
```